# Why is apt-get "not found" on a fresh install of google cloud version of Ubuntu?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Just installed ubuntu-1404-trusty-v20170517 using google cloud.  Why do I get the referenced error? Is there some reason Google doesn't include it? (They include docker and python, fer crying out loud)  Here is some relevant output:

```
 cat /etc/lsb-release 
CHROMEOS_AUSERVER=https://tools.google.com/service/update2
CHROMEOS_BOARD_APPID={76E245CF-C0D0-444D-BA50-36739C18EB00}
CHROMEOS_CANARY_APPID={90F229CE-83E2-4FAF-8479-E368A34938B1}
CHROMEOS_DEVSERVER=
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_APPID={76E245CF-C0D0-444D-BA50-36739C18EB00}
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BOARD=lakitu-signed-mpkeys
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BRANCH_NUMBER=60
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BUILDER_PATH=lakitu-release/R59-9460.60.0
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BUILD_NUMBER=9460
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BUILD_TYPE=Official Build
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_CHROME_MILESTONE=59
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_DESCRIPTION=9460.60.0 (Official Build) stable-channel lakitu 
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_NAME=Chrome OS
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_PATCH_NUMBER=0
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_TRACK=stable-channel
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_VERSION=9460.60.0
DEVICETYPE=OTHER
GOOGLE_RELEASE=9460.60.0
HWID_OVERRIDE=LAKITU DEFAULT



$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin
```

Comment: Looks like Chrome OS, not Ubuntu

Comment: And if you are really using a system with `apt-get`, you need to run `apt-get update` before installing any packages to get the package information database up-to-date.

Answer (score 3):

You have created a VM based on Container-Optimized OS image, not Ubuntu.

This is not the first question on Stackexchange from users who are not able to find APT on their VM.

NOTE: when Containers checkbox is activated in instance creation dialog, boot disk selection is getting overridden with Container-Optimized OS. This is the only OS available for Containers functionality.

See the screenshot below.

[image: GCE instance creation dialog with Containers functionality checked]